# Bitbucket losing commits on version history

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a my code on BitBucket and a strange thing is happening lately.
There are sometimes that I push a code (you can see on the commit below)

[image]

But if I try to get the version history of that file, my code is not there after a while.

[image: Version History of the file]

As you can see on the screenshots, I committed the Grunt file yesterday (01/20) and it was working fine.

Today, I did a pull and my file was reverted. When I look on the version history for the file it shows that the last commit was from 01/07.

Any ideas on what might cause this? Have anyone seen something like this?
I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a team with others?

Git never loses history, and so once you've pushed, whatever you've pushed should be there forever until someone comes later and overwrites it, and of course you can still observe deletions like that using the "git log" command.

(One caveat:  history rewriting of branches (e.g., "git push -f") can cause commits to be removed from the reachable history, so maybe someone on your team is doing that?)

Anyway, try this command to look at all commits that ever touched a "Gruntfile.js" anywhere in your repo at any reachable time in history:

```
git log --numstat --all --graph --decorate -- **/Gruntfile.js
```

The "--numstat" causes the output to include two numbers:  lines added / lines removed.

Comment: On the git log file it does not show my commit on 01/20 =(

Comment: Try "git show 5bd3a5699e2" to see if your commit is still present inside git (and just not part of a branch anymore).  If you go to "Settings" for your Bitbucket repository and notice "Location on disk," and if it's possible for you to ssh into the server and cd into that directory, try the "git show" command there to see if the Bitbucket server still knows about your commit.